# Can't get keystrokes from putty or tera term in order to config cisco switch and router

Tags: router, switch, putty

I have one router 1841 and switch 3750 and switch 2960 since last week until yesterday i test a scenario with these devices using unsuitable ips for real network and it was successful.

Today i decided to make it real and also having a connection to the internet in my scenario.

I don't unplug the Lan cables which were connected to these devices ports from last week and connecting the console cable to each devices in turn, i began to config.

At first i set the 3750 vtp mode to server and second set 2960 vtp mode to client. It takes 20 minutes and i was waiting for 2960 getting the vlan databases from 3570 and suddenly I found that the putty does not get inputs anymore from keyboard.

After that i tested other two devices and they were the same two. i in google and:

1) Num lock solution doesn't work.

2) Scroll lock doesn't work.

3) Changing the cable doesn't work.

4) I can't use pause/break to make them reset factory because it is the keyboard key and it doesn't work.

5) Any reset option from switch mode on the switch does not work i tried.

I am so confused because it seems don't have any control on these devices.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: For anyone see this post and having the same problem with putty and configuring cisco devices i have to say that i have searched so much about whole one day about this problem. I can say everything you can read in the problem, answer and comments of them could be the solution of your problem and almost they are all of the solution. don't be nervous. try to test every single solution mentioned in this page. Be prosperous.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've had similar issues on some switches when Parity is enabled.
Check your Serial settings in PuTTY.
Here's what I have set which also should be the default:

Speed (baud): 9600
Data bits: 8
Stop bits: 1
Parity: None
Flow Control: XON/XOFF

According to the getting started guide flow control should be disabled.
Have you tried changing the flow control setting to **None**? https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/switches/lan/catalyst3750/hardware/quick/guide/3750GSG3.html

Comment: I forgot to mention that, my default putty configuration is exactly like yours. also i tried some other configurations. none of them works. i guess my vtp configuration on switches would be cause of this.

Comment: I doubt changing VTP configuration would have anything to do with console connections.  VTP is only for centralized configuration of VLANs.

Are you using a Serial-to-USB adapter?  Is there another laptop or adapter/port you can test with?

Comment: My console connection is ok. Every time i restart devices i can see post configuration. Obviously the post configuration don't like the post configuration before setting 2960 to client mode and it's not normal. i don't have serial-to-USB adapter. In my opinion for now i have to be able to reset these devices to the factory mode. But i don't know any way for this without keyboard!!!

Comment: Did you see my edit? I think if you change flow control to None, your keyboard will work again.

Comment: Yes. I saw but most of them was the solutions i had tested and forgot to mention them in the post. You were right. Finally the serial-to-USB adapter helped me. The problem was the serial port of the PC i was using it. So USB was the solution. I was so exhausted yesterday. i had tested everything and i was thinking the problem was devices. Thank you so much for helping me.

Comment: Great! Glad you got it working.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue of non-responsiveness to keyboard input, and was finally able to resolve it by turning on "keyboard echo" in the Terminal settings.  The keyboard then finally started to work.  I was then able to turn off the echo setting, and it continued to work.  Maybe this will help others with the problem.